# App after being certified , gone to step 1 of app certitifcation?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, marketplace, app-hub

Recently i have submitted an to app hub, App got Certified and got a mail from microsoft saying congrats app got certified , in app hub A small dialog box in red asked for please update  additional details/ update latest package  - clicked on it redirected to all the details we have submitted during our  app submission -pressed next - next  -  says successfully app got submitted and now app life cycle status has  gone to step 1 again .

1) In my view all submitted apps section , same app shows in submitted and also in published sections.

2)Its Already 24 hours after my app got certified but my app is not in market place.

3)Application lifecycle now shows submission started - checked and submission completed - checked and 2 and 3rd steps (certification and publish ) unchecked.

4)Did i do anything wrong or is it in - track that we have to submit additional details / updated package before publishing it to windows market place.

Please help me out , and i request all of you to provide me the required guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing to worry. I faced a similar situation earlier.
It takes a few days for your app to appear in the Marketplace after successful certification. It is the problem with Microsoft Marketplace.
 However, ans to your 4th point, It is not a process to update details. It was actually offering us to submit an update for the app, if any.

Only thing you need to make sure is, whether you have given valid keywords which helps the users find your app in the marketplace.

Comment: hi thanks a lot for the reply , but my doubt is why the app lifecycle gone to step 1 of app lifecycle ? and why the same app shows up in published and also in submitted ? , nothing to worry right ? .

Comment: Is that again they will certify/ go through all the steps of certification ? , just will update the details and publish the app to market place ?

Comment: yes app will go through all the steps again, but at the same time your certified app will be published. No problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you are publishing to multiple market, it will take time for it to appear in all market and could take more than 24hrs. seem like an issue from microsoft.